# TeX capacity exceeded with a 13 columns 18 rows spreadtab

Tags: tables, xetex, fp

Originally I had a spreadsheet with 13 columns and 18 rows. Applying pdflatex or xelatex to this sheet I got:
...

```
     cell K15
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [save size=80000].
```

Then I reduced the size of the spreadsheet. With 10 columns and 16 rows or with 12 columns and 15 rows I could create pdf files with xelatex. With 10 columns  and 17 rows, with 11 columns and 16 rows or with 12 columns and 16 rows it fails with "TeX capacity exceeded". I am using:

```
rose@lynx:/home/rose/Txt/projects/ClosePackingOfSpheres/Report/MyTest(117)$ xelatex -v
XeTeX 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3-2014010319 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 SIL International and Jonathan Kew.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 52.1; using 52.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.8; using 1.2.8
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.5.0; using 2.5.3
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.2.1; using 1.2.4
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 0.9.23; using 0.9.26
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.11.0; using 2.11.1
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.8; using 1.6.10
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5
```

on a Gentoo system. Any hint is appreciated.

spreadsheet_test_10C_17R.tex (long lines with almost 500 characters):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=1cm,right=1cm,top=0.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,textheight=26cm,textwidth=18.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}       % allow Latin1 characters
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[]{fp}         % for arithmetic fixed point operation
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{caption}  %%  for captions out of figures and tables
\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\FPset\Le{10}  %% \mu m
\FPupn\Vre{2 2 root 2 div 3 \Le{} pow mul}%
\FPround\VreR\Vre{1}%
\FPupn\Are{3 2 3 root mul 2 \Le{} pow mul } %
\FPupn\RzeroF{2 3 root 2 mul 3 sub 3 div}%
\FPupn\FourPI{4 \FPpi{} mul}%
\begin{equation}
  \label{eq:faktor_1}
  f_a(r,r_p)=1-3\left[2-\frac{3}{n(r)}+\frac{1}{n(r)^2}\right]\frac{r_p}{r_p+r}
\end{equation}
\begin{centering}
\STautoround{1}
\begin{scriptsize}
\begin{spreadtab}%
  {{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}}\hline
  @$r [nm]$& @$r_0$                & @$n_R$                                    & @$n_T$                                              &  @ $S_T^{VC}(r,n_R)$               &    @$f_a(r,r_p)$                           & @ $S_T^{VC}(r,n_R)$                                                    & @ $S_T^{VC}(r,n_T)$                                                   &   @ $ S_T^{VC}(r,n_R) $                                           &  @ $ S_T^{VC}(r,n_T) $                                            \\
           &                       &                                           &                                                     &  @ $r_p=0.0$                       &                                                                      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{@ $r_p=0.3$  }                                                                                    &                                                    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{@ $ r_p=3 $}                                                  \\
  \hline
    1      &\STcopy{v} {\RzeroF*a3}&\STcopy{v} {1000*(\Vre/2)^(1/3)/(a3*2^0.5)}&\STcopy{v} {1000*(\Vre/2)^(1/3)/(a3*2^0.5)+1-6^0.5/2}&\STcopy{v}{\FourPI*(a3/1000)^2*c3^3}&                                            &   \STcopy{v} {\Are}                                                    & \STcopy{v}{\Are}                                                      &  \STcopy{v}{\Are}                                                 &   \STcopy{v}{\Are}                                                \\
    2      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &\STcopy{v}{1-3*(2-3/c4+1/c4^2)*0.3/(0.3+a4)}&\STcopy{v} {\FourPI*(a4/1000)^2*c4^3*(1-3*(2-3/c4+1/c4^2)*0.3/(0.3+a4))}&\STcopy{v}{\FourPI*(a4/1000)^2*d4^3*(1-3*(2-3/d4+1/d4^2)*0.3/(0.3+a4))}&                                                                   &                                                                   \\
    4      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
    8      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
   11.37   &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
   16      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
   20      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &\STcopy{v}{\FourPI*(a9/1000)^2*c9^3*(1-3*(2-3/c9+1/c9^2)*3/(3+a9))}&\STcopy{v}{\FourPI*(a9/1000)^2*d9^3*(1-3*(2-3/d9+1/d9^2)*3/(3+a9))}\\
   24      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
   27      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
   99      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
  125      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
  216      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
  334      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
  512      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
 1024      &                       &                                           &                                                     &                                    &                                            &                                                                        &                                                                       &                                                                   &                                                                   \\
 \hline
\end{spreadtab}
\end{scriptsize}
\captionof{table}{Numerical Values [$\mu m^2$] with different probe radii [nm]}
\label{tab:Ratio_5}
\end{centering}
\vspace{5mm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Note that you ought not use `inputenc` with XeTeX and that there is no `centering` environment in LaTeX. I get similar errors. To be honest, I think you are just pushing the limits of what TeX can be made to do, despite not being designed to do it. You can either use a spreadsheet for your table or you can increase TeX's capacity. I don't think there is anything odder going on that what it says on the tin. (Though I'm not familiar with `spreadtab` myself.)

Comment: I removed the inputenc and centering lines, but it did not change anything with respect to "TeX capacity exceeded".

Comment: I think that, here especially, LuaTeX is a good option.  This is computationally intensive.